# Become not interested in my research topic after two years of my PhD?

Tags: phd

I am supposed to finish my PhD in four years. But after two years of working on a topic, I become not interested in the topic any more. I found out that the topic is boring. What should I do? Should I continue forcing myself to work on the topic, or should I change to something more interesting? I do not want to extend my PhD since my funding only allows me to pursue the degree for four years.

EDIT:
The research topic is quite old, and I think it does not have too much potential in future development. There are already many methods to solve the problem I am working on, and doing a PhD is not using the existing methods, but inventing new ones; this is rather difficult and depressing.

Comment: Are you able to finish it anyway?

Comment: The ability to proficiently and successfully do boring things is an invaluable skill, in almost any job/role. However, if that is the path you should do or not, nobody can answer but you.

Comment: *"I found out that the topic is boring."* --- So what? A lot of good and important things are boring, and a lot of exciting and interesting things are an utter waste of time. Soap operas for example are very exciting, they are built that way. Should we all do soap operas?

Answer (score 2):

This is a conversation you need to have with your supervisor. If they are any good at supervising, they can help with strategies to either reignite your interest in your topic or salvage what you have done and apply it to something else. If you dislike your topic now, writing it up will be even worse and you may not be able to produce something passable. This is exactly what PhD supervisors are for.

Comment: I'm not convinced. The problem is more of a psychological problem, and I'm somewhat certain the supervisor will not be able to solve it, because for the supervisor the area is probably fascinating. It's also dangerous to tell your supervisor you're uninterested in their work. The OP should do a soul search within himself I reckon. Take a while to think things through.

Comment: Yikes...if you can't talk to your supervisor, who can you talk to? "Dangerous"? That is literally what they are there for. I'd consider myself a total failure as a PhD supervisor if any of mine ever thought talking to me honestly about their research interests and goals was "dangerous". If someone has that crap a supervisor, they should be looking to get out of there fast!

Comment: Also, may be field specific. In my field my supervisees' projects are not terribly closely related to mine, just thematic ties, and reframing and salvaging is certainly possible at the halfway point.

Comment: In my field it would even be research-group-specific. Some PIs are very hands-on and own the topic so much that they "hold hands" with the student, especially in the first years. Others are very hands-off and talk to their supervisees once every full moon.

Comment: I have sufficient experience to asses that, in many cases, and specifically in what seems to be here a complete rebuke of the research of the advisor (see *"The research topic is quite old, and I think it does not have too much potential in future development"*), this is not something that will lead to a productive solution. This will lead to either dropping out or to changing an advisor. I recommend then changing an advisor.
Of course, politely and gently talking about this with the advisor first is a good way to go forward.

* note the OP has added information now